# Access the values of RESX (resource) file in seperate .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, resx

How can we access the value of the Resource File from the .js file. i am able to access if the javascript is written with in the aspx page, but in the seperate page how can we access resx data.

I have tried below ways, but non work
`a.     <%$ Resources:AdminResourceMngr, L_HDR_FORM_TYPE %>
b.     <%= Resources.AdminResourceMngr.ENUM_YES %>
c.     "<%= Resources.AdminResourceMngr.L_SELECTED_COUNTRY %>"
d.     "<%= HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("AdminResourceMngr", "L_SELECTED_COUNTRY") %>"`

Comment: There's nothing native, but [this site has a way to roll your own](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/02/A-Localization-Handler-to-serve-ASPNET-Resources-to-JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks!!! I could not figure out any proper way!! I solved the issue by passing the value as the input param from apsx page